# Eigen 3.4 .reshaped()

Tags: c++, reshape, eigen

I want to reshape an Eigen vector into a matrix and then take the .colwise().sum().

The reshape command as explained in the Eigen tutorial isn't compiling (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialReshape.html)

Hence my question is as much about Eigen version numbering (has Eigen 3.4 been released?) as about the reshape command itself (my compile error says "Eigen::VectorXd has no member named 'reshaped'") and advice about an efficient alternative to the following:

`VectorXd phi = X * beta;
ArrayXd sumPhi = phi.reshaped(4,12).colwise().sum();`

Comment: Eigen 3.4 is not released yet. Please try the development branch.

Comment: It's worth noting that Eigen 3.4 is currently called Eigen 3.3.9 in the development branch. See also these [docs](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigen 3.4 has not been released (as of May 2019), I suggest trying out the development branch.

As `phi` is an actual object (and not an expression), you could achieve the same using a `Map`:

```
ArrayXd sumPhi = MatrixXd::Map(phi.data(),4,12).colwise().sum();
```

This should work with any version of Eigen (at least since 3.0), but is less safe as it does not ensure that the number of elements actually match (if `phi` has less than `4*12` elements, this could access invalid memory).